# Rails 3. how to make a nested attribute query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have shipment has one invoice; invoice belongs to shipment. The shipments table is the one that contains the customer_id.

I need to find all invoices...

- for a particular customer and
- that have customer_account_balance of 0

I have tried many different approaches but none seem to work, this last one got me error `private method select` or something like that...

```
reports_controller.rb
i = Invoice.where("customer_open_balance != 0")
s = Shipment.find_by_customer_id(@customer.id)
shipment_ids_from_invoices = i.map{|x| x.shipment_id}
@shipments = s.select{|z| shipment_ids_from_invoices.include? z.id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
@shipments = Shipment.joins(:invoice).where(:customer_id => @customer.id).where("customer_account_balance <> 0")
```

It sounds like your schema looks like this:

```
Shipment: (customer_id, ...)
Invoice: (customer_open_balance, shipment_id, ...)
```

Did you put `has_one :invoice` in Shipment.rb and `belongs_to :shipment` in Invoice.rb?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Invoice

  belongs_to :shipment

  scope :with_customer, lambda { |customer_id| joins(:shipment).where(:customer_id => customer_id) }

  scope :cero_balance, joins(:shipment).joins(:customer).where("customer_account_balance <> 0")

end
```

Then try

```
#for a particular customer with id 1
Invoice.with_customer 1

#that have customer_account_balance of 0
Invoice.cero_balance
```

Comment: It gives me some errors, but I like the approach of creating a scope. I think I'll combine answers. Thanks! :)